# Spring Data, независимый репозиторий и нативный @Query

Tags: java, spring, запрос, jpa, entity

Вот простой репозиторий:

```
interface TablitcaReposytory : CrudRepository<Tablitca, Integer> {
    
}
```

Как видите, он привязан к определённому Entity․ Естественно, когда используешь `@Query`, он использует данную таблицу, а по задаче нужно менять поля, которые не имеют своих Entity, то есть соответствующих классов в коде.

Как быть?

Answer (score 2):

При использовании `JpaRepository` (`CrudRepository`) наличие `@Entity` обязательно.

Однако, можно сделать, чтобы один класс-entity отображался не на одну таблицу, а на несколько, [используя @SecondaryTable](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-mapping-single-entity-to-multiple-tables), [также пример на SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49290711/joining-multiple-tables-using-jpa-secondarytables), соответственно тогда в `Repository` можно будет написать запросы, модифицирующие данные в связанных таблицах.

---

Альтернативный вариант (без использования Entity) -- создать самописный класс, пометить его `@Repository`, внедрить в него экземпляр `EntityManager`, который следует использовать для выполнения запросов (в т.ч. нативных) и/или при помощи Criteria API:

```java
@Repository
public class TableRepository {

    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager entityManager;

    @Transactional
    public void updateFoo(Foo foo) {
        Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery("UPDATE foo SET bar=:bar WHERE id=:id");
        query.setParameter("bar", foo.getBar());
        query.setParameter("id" foo.getId());
        query.executeUpdate();
    }

    @Transactional
    public void updateBar(Bar bar) {
        Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery("UPDATE bar SET baz=:baz WHERE id=:id");
        query.setParameter("baz", bar.getBaz());
        query.setParameter("id" bar.getId());
        query.executeUpdate();
    }
}
```

---

Ещё одна альтернатива - использовать `JdbcTemplate`.